# Failed to install  "gem install eventmachine". I need starling in my project, for starling i need to install eventmachine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error on my console

```
root@comp09:~# gem install eventmachine
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... yes
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking for epoll_create() in sys/epoll.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_TRAP_IMMEDIATE -DHAVE_RBTRAP -DHAVE_INOTIFY_INIT -DHAVE_INOTIFY -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_EPOLL_CREATE -DHAVE_EPOLL -DWITH_SSL    -fPIC -O2 -g -Wall -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long     -o rubymain.o -c rubymain.cpp
make: I.: Command not found
make: [rubymain.o] Error 127 (ignored)
I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_TRAP_IMMEDIATE -DHAVE_RBTRAP -DHAVE_INOTIFY_INIT -DHAVE_INOTIFY -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_EPOLL_CREATE -DHAVE_EPOLL -DWITH_SSL    -fPIC -O2 -g -Wall -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long     -o em.o -c em.cpp
make: I.: Command not found
```

For any help and suggestion it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have fixed up the indentation of your console output. Please use a four-space indent in the future when showing code or output.

Comment: this "I." (in make: I.: Command not found) means that the build did not know which compiler to use which should be g++.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 11.10 installing eventmachine.
The difference being (near the end of the logs)

```
make: g++: Command not found
```

instead of

```
make: I.: Command not found
```

This issue is related with C++ on GCC and resolved by installing build-essential

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 4):

You may also be missing the ruby dev packages.  Depending on what version of ruby you are using, this could be ruby-dev, ruby1.8-dev, ruby1.9-dev, or ruby1.9.1-dev.  I had the same problem, and installed ruby1.9-dev and ruby1.9.1-dev and that solved my issue.

This is the site that led me to try this approach: http://ruby.about.com/od/faqs/qt/Extconf-Rb-1-In-Require-No-Such-File-To-Load-Mkmf-Loaderror.htm

Comment: My ruby version is ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [x86_64-linux] and my OS is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx)

Comment: This worked on Debian as the ruby-dev is missing. After installing, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, this is how resolved it [NOTE: I am using ubuntu, so at "g++" you have to use "gcc" if you are using any other OS]:

At first I cloned the repository to my local machine, and did some changes, have a look at the procedure below:

```
git clone git://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git
cd eventmachine
gem install rake-compiler
rake-compiler cross-ruby VERSION=x.x.x-px
```

At the place of x.x.x-px you have to use your ruby version. see the list of available version of ruby which are compatible with rake-compiler [here](http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/01/22/rake-compiler-updated-list-of-supported-ruby-versions-for-cross-compilation/)

Then go and put this: `CONFIG['CXX'] = "g++"` in **/eventmachine/ext/extconf.rb** and **/eventmachine/ext/fastfilereader/extconf.rb** files, right below `require 'mkmf'` line.
then do: `rake gem` and after that: `rake gem:install`

It worked for me, hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev build-essential` then `sudo gem install eventmachine`. That solved it for me.

Comment: I had same issue and this answer solved my issue. thanks @Online Sid

Answer (score 1):

from docs .

> EventMachine may require the following
>   dependencies, depending on your
>   specific usage:
>
> ```
> * OpenSSL
> * libstd++ (some systems, such as debian, may require an explicit
> ```
>
> install in order for the compiler to
>   support this)

Try to install it , if you are using debian

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

Comment: Hi Andrea, Thanks for answer. I have already installed c++ manually. But it wont working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to run *rvm requirements* and follow the instructions in *Additional Dependencies*.

Answer (score 1):

For all users running openSUSE you'll need to execute this command :

```
zypper in -t pattern devel_C_C++
```

For simplicity we can say that this is the equivalent of this command under Ubuntu :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```